# Implementing ExactTarget Journey Builder with Swift

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios, journeybuilder, mobilepush-ios

I'm trying to implement push notifications using the Journey Builder SDK in a Swift Application for iOS with the latest version of the SDK (4.1.0) https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/JB4A-SDK-iOS.

After adding the SDK and creating the Bridging-Header file, I get to use the sdk correctly. However, wen trying to use the method

ETPush.pushManager().configureSDKWithAppID()

I'm only getting Void methods and not Bool as they appear to be in ETPush.h

```
-(BOOL)configureSDKWithAppID:(NSString *)etAppID
          andAccessToken:(NSString *)accessToken
           withAnalytics:(BOOL)analyticsState
     andLocationServices:(BOOL)locState
           andCloudPages:(BOOL)cpState
         withPIAnalytics:(BOOL)pIAnalyticsState
                   error:(NSError **)configureError;
```

This is my AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //        var error: NSError? = nil
    var successful:Bool? = false

    // Set to YES to enable logging while debugging
    ETPush.setETLoggerToRequiredState(true)

    //USING DEBUG KEYS
    // configure and set initial settings of the JB4ASDK
    do{
        try  successful = ETPush.pushManager().configureSDKWithAppID(kETAppID_Debug, andAccessToken: kETAccessToken_Debug, withAnalytics: true, andLocationServices: true, andCloudPages: true, withPIAnalytics:true)

    }catch{
       print("ERROR")
    }

    if successful != nil{
        if successful == false{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
                // something failed in the configureSDKWithAppID call - show what the error is

                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Failed configureSDKWithAppID!", message: "Failed configureSDKWithAppID!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            })
        }else{

            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge , .Sound], categories: nil)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)


            ETPush.pushManager().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            ETPush.pushManager().registerForRemoteNotifications()

            // inform the JB4ASDK of the launch options - possibly UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey or UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey
            ETPush.pushManager().applicationLaunchedWithOptions(launchOptions)

            // This method is required in order for location messaging to work and the user's location to be processed
            ETLocationManager.sharedInstance().startWatchingLocation()
        }
    }


    return true
}
```

I'm getting a "Cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'Bool'" error.

Am I missing something? Shouldn't it return Bool?

I'm not even getting a Bool option with the helper:

[image]